# SQL Server : how to get a percent column from the total with pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this query to get the data from a SQL Server table and want to get also the percentages in the last column like this.

The % column must somethink like this or ? =

```
[Jahr] = SUM([Januar] + [Februar]... + [Dezember]) / [Prio] = ISNULL(CAST(Priority as nvarchar(10)),'Total')

% =  132 / 1832 =   7%
% =  126 / 1832 =   7%
% = 1563 / 1832 =  85%
% =   11 / 1832 =   1%
% = 1832 / 1832 = 100%
```

Table:

```
Prio    …   Sep Okt Nov Dez Year    Month    %
Prio0   …   27  18  0   0   132       15     7%
Prio1   …   17  3   0   0   126       14     7%
Prio2   …   512 225 0   0   1563     174    85%
Prio3   …   1   7   0   0   11         1     1%
Total   …   557 253 0   0   1832     204   100%
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  [Prio]        = ISNULL(CAST(Priority as nvarchar(10)),'Total')
, [Januar]      = SUM([Januar])
, [Februar]     = SUM([Februar])
, [März]        = SUM([März])
, [April]       = SUM([April])
, [Mai]         = SUM([Mai])
, [Juni]        = SUM([Juni])
, [Juli]        = SUM([Juli])
, [August]      = SUM([August])
, [September]   = SUM([September])
, [Oktober]     = SUM([Oktober])
, [November]    = SUM([November])
, [Dezember]    = SUM([Dezember])
, [Jahr]        = SUM([Januar] + [Februar] + [März] + [April] + [Mai] + [Juni] + [Juli] + [August] + [September] + [Oktober] + [November] + [Dezember])
, [Durchschnitt je Monat]   = CAST(SUM([Januar] + [Februar] + [März] + [April] + [Mai] + [Juni] + [Juli] + [August] + [September] + [Oktober] + [November] + [Dezember]) AS decimal) / DATEPART(month, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
FROM    
    (SELECT  
         ISNULL(a.Priority, '_N/A') Priority,
         DATENAME(mm, a.Date) as [month]
     FROM    
         DataTable a
     WHERE  
         YEAR(Date) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())) ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT([month])
    FOR [month] in ([Januar],[Februar],[März],[April],[Mai],[Juni],[Juli],[August],[September],[Oktober],[November],[Dezember])
) AS PivotTable

GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(Priority)
```

How do I get the percentages in the last column?

Thanks very much!
Ben

Comment: Please explain what calculation you want for the percentage. Don't make us guess.

Comment: sorry, i want to get the percent from each prio row [year] / [Total] year. i.e. Prio0 -> 132 / 1832 = 7%